# JUnit Test appears to not be working properly when comparing java.awt.Color objects

Tags: java, junit, junit4, equals

Using this piece of code:

```
@Test
public void testBallSize() {
    Ball b = new Ball(1f,1f,0.5f,0.5f, Color.WHITE);
    assertEquals("Color of the ball should be white.", Color.WHITE, b.getColor());

}
```

Produced:

```
   java.lang.AssertionError: Color of the ball should be white. expected: java.awt.Color<java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]> but was: java.awt.Color<java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]>
            at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
            at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
            at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
            at BallTest.testBallSize(BallTest.java:18)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
            at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
            at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
            at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
            at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The colors appear to be the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the alpha values of the two colors are different? According to the docs: `The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a Color object that has the same red, green, blue, and alpha values as this object.`

Comment: More information is required about your code. Please add more code.

Comment: I think @DanielZolnai is right. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Great! The answer was in alpha value. For some reason, class picked default alpha value 127, and that's the reason why it wasn't showing true even though other color values were correct. Please, make it an answer and I will declare this q. closed. :-) @DanielZolnai

Comment: But still, this is interesting... why alphas were different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the alpha values of the two colors are different?

According to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a
>   Color object that has the same red, green, blue, and alpha values as
>   this object.